# How to get the assertion data in SoapUI using Groovy script?

Tags: api, groovy, soapui, assertion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0rBU.png)

I have a SOAP request. Some times it gives a null/empty response. I have added assertion for the request and I am getting the assertion status and description. But how can I get the message "null/empty response"(screen shot of the message is attached) using the Groovy script.

```
def assertionsList = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestStepByName(""+testStep[i]+"").getAssertionList()

assertioncounter = assertionsList.size()

for( e in assertionsList){                                        
     log.info e.status
     log.info e.DESCRIPTION
    }
```

Comment: Maybe getErrors() https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/5.5.0/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestAssertion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   assertioncounter = assertionsList.size()
   for(e in assertionsList)
   {   
     log.info e.status
     log.info e.DESCRIPTION
     error = e.getErrors()
     if (error != null)
     {
        log.info e.error[0].getMessage()
     }
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).